# Cause: cannot find com.example.exampleCombant.Appname.Database: com.example.example.appname.DataBase found in com/Database.class

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I can't run my app Because of this problem i have created an SQL lite data base using SQL lite Open Helper and added the table that i need but i can't run the app
any help please? i have to finish the app on Sunday to give it to my teacher. I have tried to delete the app from my testing device and re installing it, and checked my app files but found nothing

```
package com.mohnad.theeducationnewera.marksbook;

import android.content.Context;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;

public class DataBase extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
    private static final String database_name = "DB";
    private static final int database_vesion =1;
    private static final String UID = "id";
    private static final String name = "Name";
    private static final String work_mark = "Works Mark";
    private static final String test_mark = "Tests mark";
    private static final String tableName = "Students";
    private Context context;
    private static final String DROP_TABLE = "DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " +tableName;
    private static final String CREATE_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE " +tableName+" " +
        " ("+UID+" INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT," +
        " "+name+" TEXT VARCHAR(255))," +
        " "+work_mark+" INTEGER ," +
        " "+test_mark+" INTEGER ;";

    public DataBase(Context context) {
        super(context, database_name,null, database_vesion);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        db.execSQL(CREATE_TABLE);
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        db.execSQL(DROP_TABLE);
    }
}
```

Comment: Why would `Database.class` be in a `com` folder? Why does the `Database.class` file say `com.example.example.appname.DataBase` when your source code says the package name is `com.mohnad.theeducationnewera.marksbook`. --- Seems like you have some old `Database.class` file you need to delete from your file system, then recompile what you have and try again.

Comment: That source file should be in a `com/mohnad/theeducationnewera/marksbook/DataBase.java` and should be compiled to a file named `com/mohnad/theeducationnewera/marksbook/DataBase.class`. There should be no `com/example/example/appname` folders related to these files.

Comment: @Andreas  I only have this Data Base inside my C:\Users\asus--2018\AndroidStudioProjects\MarksBook\app\src\main\java\com\mohnad\theeducationnewera\marksbook folder, I have deleted all old data bases can you please give me a specific folder to look in where i can find the wrong  data base ?

Comment: Thanks guys!!!!! It works, I for got that i have imported io.realm to my app
I have deleted the imports in the gradle and in my activity class and it works
Thanks alot guys you made out my day
now I can complete the app hopefully i can finish it tomorrow.
Thanks again.
by the way, my problem is solved, should i deleted to make place to another problems or keep it?

Answer (score 0):

first you must be sure that manifest have only one LAUNCHER

```
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
```

second in DBHelper

```
@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
    db.execSQL(DROP_TABLE);
//add line below
    onCreate(db);
}
```

give me the feed back after run it 
good luck

Comment: I have a space between the execSQL and the ONCreate method 
it's working, thanks alot